# Javascript Canvas Breakout Collision Detection Issue

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm coding a breakout game in `JavaScript` and have an issue with the paddle collision detection.

On running the program, all collisions of the ball with the paddle are fine until the first time it misses. At this point the program sets the ball back in the center and sends it off again. However this time around the paddle surface is being ignored yet the code beyond that point to determine the ball has left the boundary is working as when the ball leaves the screen the next time it is still reset.

There is a `jsFiddle` of the code is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Geejayz/bnLbzgg0/).

I've tried several `if/else` variations to mend it but can't figure out why the code is ignored at a later point.

**Code snippet**

```js
var canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
var surface = canvas.getContext("2d");
var button = document.querySelector("button");

button.addEventListener("click", playGame, false);

//Game results
var score = 0;
var lives = 4;
var gameOver = false;

//Create a ball object
var ball = {
 radius: 10,
 x: canvas.height - 30,
 y: canvas.width/2,
 dx: 3,
 dy: -3,
};

//Create a paddle object
var paddle = {
 width: 75,
 height: 10,
 x: (canvas.width -75)/2,
 y: canvas.height - 10
};

//add key controls
document.addEventListener("keydown", keydownHandler, false);
document.addEventListener("keyup", keyupHandler, false);
var moveLeft = false;
var moveRight = false;

function playGame() {
 requestAnimationFrame (playGame, canvas);

  render();
  moveBall();
  movePaddle();

}



function render() {
 //Clear the canvas surface
 surface.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
 
 drawBall();
 drawPaddle();
 
 //Keep ball within boundary
 if(ball.x + ball.dx < 0 + ball.radius || ball.x + ball.dx > canvas.width - ball.radius ) {
   //Reverse the direction of the ball in x direction
  ball.dx = -ball.dx;
 }
 if(ball.y + ball.dy < 0 + ball.radius ) {
  //Reverse the direction of the ball in the y direction
  ball.dy = -ball.dy; 
 }
 
 //Make ball bounce of top surface of paddle
 if(Math.floor(ball.y) === Math.floor(canvas.height - ball.radius - paddle.height) &&
  ball.x + ball.radius > paddle.x && ball.x - ball.radius < paddle.x + paddle.width) {
   //ball has hit paddle
   ball.dy = -ball.dy;
 }
 
 if (ball.y + ball.dy > canvas.height + ball.radius) {
   //ball has gone outside area
   console.log('Out of Bounds');
   
   //Set new ball position
   ball.y = canvas.height -30;
   ball.x = canvas.width/2;
   ball.dy = -ball.dy;
 }
 
}
 

function drawBall() {
 surface.beginPath();
 surface.arc(ball.x,ball.y,ball.radius,0, Math.PI*2);
 surface.fillStyle = "yellow";
 surface.fill();
 surface.closePath();
}

function drawPaddle() {
 surface.beginPath();
 surface.rect(paddle.x, paddle.y, paddle.width, paddle.height);
 surface.fillStyle = "lightblue";
 surface.fill();
 surface.closePath();
}

function movePaddle() {
 if (moveLeft && paddle.x > 0) {
  paddle.x -= 7;
 }
 if (moveRight && paddle.x + paddle.width < canvas.width) {
  paddle.x +=7;
 }
}

function moveBall() {
 //Give ball a starting velocity
 ball.x += ball.dx;
 ball.y += ball.dy;
}

function keydownHandler(event) {
 if(event.keyCode === 37) {
  moveLeft = true;
 }
 if(event.keyCode === 39) {
  moveRight = true;
 }
}

function keyupHandler(event) {
 if(event.keyCode === 37) {
  moveLeft = false;
 }
 if(event.keyCode === 39) {
  moveRight = false;
 }
}

function scoreboard() {
 surface.font = "20px Arial";
 surface.fillStyle = "#00FF00";
 surface.fillText("Score: " + score, 8, 20);
 surface.fillText("Lives: " + lives, 730, 20);
}
```

```css
canvas {
 background-color: #000;
 border: 3px solid green;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="800" height="480"></canvas>

<button>Run</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got there in the end.

My code was expecting an exact match of the ball surface on the paddle surface. However, as the increments are 3 pixels at a time there is a point where the ball surface is just above the paddle surface and on the next frame it is just beyond it.

I fixed by amending to a "greater than paddle surface and less than canvas area" condition.

Updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/Geejayz/bnLbzgg0/6/ :

```js
var canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
var surface = canvas.getContext("2d");
var button = document.querySelector("button");

button.addEventListener("click", playGame, false);

//Game results
var score = 0;
var lives = 4;
var gameOver = false;

//Create a ball object
var ball = {
 radius: 10,
 x: canvas.height - 30,
 y: canvas.width/2,
 dx: 3,
 dy: -3,
};

//Create a paddle object
var paddle = {
 width: 75,
 height: 10,
 x: (canvas.width -75)/2,
 y: canvas.height - 10
};

//add key controls
document.addEventListener("keydown", keydownHandler, false);
document.addEventListener("keyup", keyupHandler, false);
var moveLeft = false;
var moveRight = false;

function playGame() {
 requestAnimationFrame (playGame, canvas);

  render();
  moveBall();
  movePaddle();

}



function render() {
 //Clear the canvas surface
 surface.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
 
 drawBall();
 drawPaddle();
 
 //Keep ball within boundary
 if(ball.x + ball.dx < 0 + ball.radius || ball.x + ball.dx > canvas.width - ball.radius ) {
   //Reverse the direction of the ball in x direction
  ball.dx = -ball.dx;
 }
 if(ball.y + ball.dy < 0 + ball.radius ) {
  //Reverse the direction of the ball in the y direction
  ball.dy = -ball.dy; 
 }
 
 //Make ball bounce of top surface of paddle
 if(ball.y > canvas.height - ball.radius - paddle.height &&
  ball.y < canvas.height - ball.radius &&
  ball.x + ball.radius > paddle.x && ball.x - ball.radius < paddle.x + paddle.width) {
   //ball has hit paddle
   ball.dy = -ball.dy;
 }
 
 if (ball.y + ball.dy > canvas.height + ball.radius) {
   //ball has gone outside area
   console.log('Out of Bounds');
   
   //Set new ball position
   ball.y = canvas.height -30;
   ball.x = canvas.width/2;
   ball.dy = -ball.dy;
 }
 
}
 

function drawBall() {
 surface.beginPath();
 surface.arc(ball.x,ball.y,ball.radius,0, Math.PI*2);
 surface.fillStyle = "yellow";
 surface.fill();
 surface.closePath();
}

function drawPaddle() {
 surface.beginPath();
 surface.rect(paddle.x, paddle.y, paddle.width, paddle.height);
 surface.fillStyle = "lightblue";
 surface.fill();
 surface.closePath();
}

function movePaddle() {
 if (moveLeft && paddle.x > 0) {
  paddle.x -= 7;
 }
 if (moveRight && paddle.x + paddle.width < canvas.width) {
  paddle.x +=7;
 }
}

function moveBall() {
 //Give ball a starting velocity
 ball.x += ball.dx;
 ball.y += ball.dy;
}

function keydownHandler(event) {
 if(event.keyCode === 37) {
  moveLeft = true;
 }
 if(event.keyCode === 39) {
  moveRight = true;
 }
}

function keyupHandler(event) {
 if(event.keyCode === 37) {
  moveLeft = false;
 }
 if(event.keyCode === 39) {
  moveRight = false;
 }
}

function scoreboard() {
 surface.font = "20px Arial";
 surface.fillStyle = "#00FF00";
 surface.fillText("Score: " + score, 8, 20);
 surface.fillText("Lives: " + lives, 730, 20);
}
```

```css
canvas {
 background-color: #000;
 border: 3px solid green;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="800" height="480"></canvas>

<button>Run</button>
```

(Also thanks to AgataB and zow for the edits - it has been a while since I posted. I probably still haven't gotten this post perfect either.).

Comment: Please note that jsfiddles actually need code with them. Learn to read the messages the system gives you when it prevents you from posting, please.